# I'm trying to create a javascript flavored Regex expression that will returned multiple of a named group

Tags: regex

Sample Text:

{**Keyword1**}words1 words1 words1{**\Keyword1**}{**Keyword2**}words2 words2 words2{**\Keyword2**}
{**Keyword3**}words3 words3 words3{**\Keyword3**}{**Keyword1**}words4 words4 words4{**\Keyword1**}
{**Keyword2**}words5 words5 words5{**\Keyword2**}{**Keyword1**}words6 words6 words6{**\Keyword1**}

I have this Current Expression:

(?(?<={Keyword1})[\s\S]*(?={\Keyword1}))

- **Group Keyword1** - words1 words1 words1{\Keyword1}{Keyword2}words2 words2 words2{\Keyword2}
  {Keyword3}words3 words3 words3{\Keyword3}{Keyword1}words4 words4 words4{\Keyword1}
  {Keyword2}words5 words5 words5{\Keyword2}{Keyword1}words6 words6 words6

I want Regex Match:

- **Group Keyword1** - words1 words1 words1
- **Group Keyword1** - words4 words4 words4
- **Group Keyword1** - words6 words6 words6

Comment: `[\s\S]*` is greedy, use `[\s\S]*?` lazy version.

Comment: Thank you so much! That solved it.